# Issues with keen slider on route change in safari

Tags: next.js

I'm not totally clear on the issue keenslider breaks when changing route - the page is jumping scroll position to the keenslider element on route change start

```
import { useKeenSlider } from 'keen-slider/react'
import 'keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css'



const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState<number>(0)
      const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false)
      const [ref, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider<HTMLDivElement>({
        initial: 0,
        defaultAnimation: {
          duration: 0.4,
        },
        slideChanged(s) {
          setCurrentSlide(s.track.details.rel)
        },
        created() {
          setLoaded(true)
        },
      })
```

Comment: Can you add your full component code?  this appears like it's not wrapped in a React component at all.